# PL SQL: How to Concatenate Loop variable with PATH

Tags: oracle, plsql, xmltable

I am using a following PL SQL for loop to insert multiple xml node values into table:

```
FOR I IN 1..count_role LOOP

INSERT INTO TABLE_EMPLOYEE (EMP_ID, EMP_JOB) 
        SELECT x.EMP_ID, x.EMP_JOB 
        FROM XMLTABLE('/role_list'
        PASSING xmlData
        COLUMNS  EMP_ID  VARCHAR2(10)     PATH   'employee_id',                                                        
                 EMP_JOB VARCHAR2(30)     PATH   'job['||I||']/job_name'
        ) x;

END Loop;
```

In the above code this Concatenation `'job['||I||']/job_name'`Not working.

It is showing error

`PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
 PL/SQL: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`
However if i use constants like `'job[1]/job_name'`then it works nice.
 Here is my sample input xml:

```
<role_list>
<employee_id>123</employee_id>
<job>
<job_name>job1</job_name>
</job>
<job>
<job_name>job2</job_name>
</job>
</role_list>
```

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT X.EMP_ID, X.EMP_JOB 
        FROM XMLTABLE('/role_list/job[$count]'
        PASSING xmlData, I AS "count"
        COLUMNS  EMP_ID  VARCHAR2(10)     PATH   'employee_id',                                                        
                 EMP_JOB VARCHAR2(30)     PATH   'job_name'
        ) X;
```

Comment: Thanks @Praneeth Gudumasu. I want to  know that is this`$count`variable from pl sql or php?

Answer (score 0):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
LV_X XMLTYPE := XMLTYPE('<STUDENT><NAME type="1">PRANEETH</NAME></STUDENT>');
LV_NAME VARCHAR2(200);
LV_NUMBER NUMBER := 1;
BEGIN
SELECT X.NAME
 INTO LV_NAME
        FROM XMLTABLE('/STUDENT,NAME[@type = $count]'
        PASSING LV_X, LV_NUMBER AS "count"
        COLUMNS  NAME  VARCHAR2(100)     PATH   'NAME'                                                     

        ) X;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lv_namE);
END;
/
output :praneeth
```

Comment: Hello @Praneeth Gudumasu. Can you please suggest coding change needed in my code.thanks